# Reflow paragraph indented with ">" in Vim

Tags: vim, formatting, indentation, reflow

I use (g)Vim to edit emails, and I frequently have a need to reflow long lines in indented paragraphs, which start with `>`, `>>`, etc.

For example, imagining my `textwidth` is set very short:

```
> Line 1 is short.
> Line 2 is very long, really, I mean, far too long, what a mess.
> Line 3 not so.
```

When I format with something like `{gq}`, this should become something like:

```
> Line 1 is short. Line 2 is very 
> long, really, I mean, far too 
> long, what a mess. Line 3 not so.
```

How can I make it do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `ftplugin` to do this:

```
set comments=fb:*,fb:-,b:>,b:>>,b:>>>,b:>>>>                                    
set autoindent
```

The last part of the first line is where the action happens - this provides a "comment block" prefix of `>`, `>>`, etc, separated by a blank.

This will only work up the 4th level of indentation, but I could add more if needed.

As an aside, the first two mean I get indented lists easily like this:

```
* List item is very long, it
  just keeps going and going 
  and going
- And this one uses a dash as
  a bullet point
```

Edit: as Dhruva Sagar said, the `formatoptions` will determine whether I can format comments at all with `{gq}`. The above just says what the comment prefixes are.

Answer (score 2):

Vim has built-in support for this. Vim has an option `formatoptions` that allows you to specify several such things. Check `:h fo-table` for more details.

For the specific query you have, you would want to add `set formatoptions+=q` though I would prefer `set formatoptions+=tcroq` for even better handling of such formatting.

There are also other gems in `fo-table`, I personally use this setting : `set formatoptions=njtcroql`

Comment: This is all true, but I already had `formatoptions` set to `tcq`. Good tips about the others and the help file.